# How can only "set timestamp " statement be in MySQL slow logs

Tags: mysql

I am using Percona 5.1.66-14.2. Our slow logs are configured to records SQLs taking more than 500 millisecs (0.5sec).

I am seeing only set timestamp statement in slow logs. Does semicolon (;) after SET timestamp in slow-logs signifies something?

```
# Time: 130612  2:01:55
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 8  Schema: db_cache  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 0.667233  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 0
# Bytes_sent: 1462  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
SET timestamp=1371027715;
;
# Time: 130612  2:01:57
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 8  Schema: db_cache  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 0.524655  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 0
# Bytes_sent: 1339  Tmp_tables: 1  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
SET timestamp=1371027717;
;
# Time: 130612  2:01:58
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 8  Schema: db_cache  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 0.775974  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 0
# Bytes_sent: 1374  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
SET timestamp=1371027718;
;
# Time: 130612  2:02:00
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 8  Schema: db_cache  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 0.986338  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 0
# Bytes_sent: 1987  Tmp_tables: 1  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
SET timestamp=1371027720;
;**
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: "*Does semicolon (;) after SET timestamp in slow-logs signifies something?*"

Comment: It's not the `SET timestamp`, but whatever comes after is isn't correctly logged apparently. The fact that it sometimes creates temp tables is a hint that at least 'something' is done... If you have this problem _very_ ooften, you might consider enabling the general log for a little while until you get a hit in the slow log, and compare the 2 (search mainly on thread id). Alternatively, seeing as it's `root`, you could try and see what enabling `log-slow-admin-statements` does.